# Java reverse engineering with Papyrus Software Designer in Eclipse Version: Neon.3 (4.6.3)

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, reverse-engineering, papyrus

I want to Reverse-engineer a Registered package of my workspace, so I go to model explorer, click on mouse right button, where I was supposed to see a menu with the option **import**, with the menu options:

- Import Registered Profile
- Import Registered Package
- Import Package From User Model

[image]

But this is what I see:

[image]

and this is the version of Papyrus

[image]

I also tried to drag-n-drop the package to be reverse engineered from package explorer to the class diagram, but it didn't work out..

[image]

Answer (score 6):

One way is:

1. create a Papyrus project with an empty class diagram
2. drag-n-drop the package to be reverse engineered from package explorer to the class diagram
3. the Reverse Code dialog should appear, click OK
4. objects will draw in the diagram

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1078042/) pointed me in the right direction.

- Right click on the object (I did a class)
- Filter-->Show/Hide    contents.

Boom! They are there.  Not sure why they aren't by default, but there they are!